# What does let oneself into somewhere mean?

Tags: idioms, let

One of my friends has explained the following to clear the difference between these.

Nevertheless, I cannot understand them, well. In addition, are they correct?

Sophie let herself quickly into the red house.

Sophie quickly went into the red house.
ANSWERS

They pretty much mean the same thing. Except that Sophie quickly went into the red house could mean that someone else let her in, too.

To let oneself into implies an unlocking or at least physical opening of the entrance, not just entering.

to let someone in' is not necessarily the same as 'to go in' or 'to allow in'. It means someone has eg opened the door or unlocked the door.

Comment: Your first example is a bit "off". I'm sure most native speakers would much prefer *"Sophie quickly let herself in [to] the red house."* Also note that the ***to*** is optional, but the idiomatic usage is ***let [someone] in***; you can't switch it to ***into*** like that.

Answer (score 3):

*Let someone in* or *let someone out* means to enable someone to come in or get out of somewhere.

> Hi, the door is locked. Could you *let me in*, please?
>   Hey! I want to go home! *Let me out* of here!

If you would address me with these lines, I could *let you in* to  my house, or I could *let you out* of the cage.

As a result, you would probably *get* into my house, or *get* out of the cage.

Now, if the person that you let in or out is yourself, then you do not need anyone else to allow you or enable you to get into or out of something. So if you have the key to my house and to the cage, you can say:

> Hi, the door was locked. I let myself in.
>   I wanted to go home, so I let myself out of there.

Comment: Though you can also say it if all you did was give yourself permission to enter—"The door was unlocked, so I let myself in."

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have answered your own question. Are you just looking for confirmation?

Yes, "to let oneself in" means that you entered a place on your own initiative, without being admitted by someone else. It is normally used in a context where people expect that someone else would have to unlock the door for you or at least give you permission.

Like if you went to a friend's house and no one was home, but the door was unlocked, and so you just walked in and sat down to wait for them, you could say, "I let myself in."

Usually "letting yourself in" implies trespassing someplace that you are not legally allowed to be, or at least rudeness in not waiting for an authorized person to admit you. But someone could say, "If you get there before me, just let yourself in", in which case it would be authorized, just in a slightly unconventional way.